Is there a library to do Butterworth and Savitsky-Golay filtering in PHP?
I am new to signal processing and have a requirement to apply Butterworth and Savitzky-Golay to a PPG signal. I have read that matlab can handle it but I am a PHP guy. Can I run Matlab on my server and call it as a linux library from php with an exec command, or similar? I have the pre-filtered data that I just need to feed into a program to apply the filter, then I can handle graphing the results.
So my question is really for advice. What is the best way to approach this from a PHP guy standpoint? I don't need a UI solution. This has to be implemented in large volume. I want to receive the data in my php endpoint, apply the detrending and moving average filters myself, then call a server-side function (can be compiled C or C++), passing it my datastream and get back a filtered stream. I need to do this for both a butterworth (3rd order with defined corner frequencies) and then pass that to a 3rd order polynomial Savitzky-Golay filter and get that data back as well.
Any advice is welcome.

What is Savitzky-Golay filtering?  Isn't it just fitting an $N$-th order polynomial to data using the least-squares measure of fit?  And then sliding the window over?

@robertbristow-johnson yep, I remember it as "I want to design a filter that's equivalent to LS estimate using an nth order polynomial, and then just convolving with that filter's impulse response". Since PPG observations can often be analyzed in chunks (if there's no pulse in a finger for 5 minutes … you probably should have alerted someone 4 min 45 ago), this would be a classical use case for fast convolution


Can I run Matlab on my server and call it as a linux library from php with an exec command, or similar?

That's a question of Matlab license; there's a realistic chance you are not allowed to use your version of Matlab in a server application accessible to people without Matlab licenses. But that's something you need to make clear with The Mathworks.
Other than that, exec: aside from the obvious security implications, that would be very slow and inefficient. You'd more like build a server application in Matlab with which you exchange data from your PHP script.
More realistically, you'd let your Matlab generate C/C++ code and use that as a native function from your PHP. Not inherently fun, because some things need some massaging before Matlab's idea of a build system agrees with the realities of your PHP runtime, but doable.
But frankly: The Butterworth filter (not a typical filter for a digital implementation, unless you have the mathematical reason to go for exactly that!) is a straightforward IIR – you can use matlab to calculate the coefficients once, and use them with any signal processing library of your choice – for example, liquid-dsp has such filter routines.
Same for the S-G filter: It's just an FIR – you can do the coefficient design in Matlab and use the coefficients in any language you like to apply an FIR filter. Frankly, I'd even say: learning to write an FIR filter convolution to an input array is probably a good exercise for a beginner in C++ or C.
I'd recommend you learn enough C++ (or C) to write these in your first PHP extension library. Especially since you're probably using a readily-designed set of coefficients in both cases,

php endpoint, apply the detrending and moving average filters

Don't do that in PHP. Pretty much the worst modern programming language for array processing of samples; absorb that into your signal processing done in another language.
I'd honestly just drop PHP and use a scripting language with a larger signal processing user base. A lot of us here do our day-to-day signal processing, signal analysis and visualization in Python. Fast enough for many jobs, and there's many easy to use libraries, sensible data types for DSP work, and a really big canon of existing software.

This has to be implemented in large volume.

When people say things like "large volume", they mean very different things; if you would be to apply my understanding of the term, PHP probably would be a performance non-starter; the mathematical operations you plan to do are so quick on modern CPUs that the overhead of such a language runtime will dominate the time spent. But I doubt that's the case for you; "PPG data" sounds like a few thousand time values per data point, and maybe a few thousand data points; and not having to process multiple million samples per second (which, by the way, should really be no significant issue, unless your digitized Butterworth approximation is exceedingly long, which I doubt for the PPG use case).

Thanks for the very comprehensive reply. Php is just my front-end web interface. My linux server receives a 30MB file for each patient each night. That server can do the signal processing in c/c++ or any language, then I pass the filtered signals on to the engineering server where the machine language models are applied to calculate the results. Butterworth and S_G filters are what the engineering firm we hired used and recommended. They provided parameters for Butterworth and for the S_G. What I am looking for is a server-side library that can handle these filters and return a result.

Then my answer addresses your needs pretty exactly.
